# Solve route with line restriction is not working as expected

Tags: arcmap, network-analyst, barriers

I am implementing the routing solution with a point, line, and polygon restriction. Whenever we are passing the line restriction, it's restricting travel on all intersecting roads.

To explain the problem we choose below location and trying to add two restrictions.

[image]

Here we are proving the routing_streets object id for both restrictions.

[image]

Because the where clause has object id of underpass road restriction is applicable to both roads.

[image]
[image]

If we pass only one restriction then it's working fine but we have many restrictions. How to add all the restrictions in one request to avoid this problem?

[image]

[image]